# How to open a .pre file in R?

Tags: r

I am wondering how to open a .pre file in R. I can open the file in notepad, and see it clearly on Windows.

I also have an object called "newfiles" that lists many .pre files, but when I try to pull these files into R, I get the error message below.

Here is the code I have for my files:

```
newfiles <- dir("~/Desktop/_preFiles_byGrid")

> newfile
[1] "262778 _PRISM.pre"

> head(newfiles)
[1] "262778 _PRISM.pre" "262779 _PRISM.pre" "262780 _PRISM.pre" "262781 _PRISM.pre" "262782 _PRISM.pre" "262783 _PRISM.pre"



for (newfile in newfiles) {
n <- read.table(file.path("_preFiles_byGrid", newfile), sep=",", as.is=TRUE, header=FALSE)
}

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '_preFiles_byGrid/262778 _PRISM.pre': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Be sure to be in the right working directory. Use `setwd(...)` to set it. Control it using `dir()`.

Comment: Thanks. I should be in the right working directory, since it lists all of the correct files in my global environment.

Comment: Can you add some codes regarding open files.

Comment: Where is your actual code that's generating this error?

Comment: @WenlongLiu - added code

Comment: Add `full.names = TRUE` to your `dir()` call. Then you will get the full path to the file so you won't have to do `file.path()` later. (It's suspicious that your `file.path()` call is missing the "~/Desktop/" part). Also it's unclear where the "_DataSummary.zip" part is coming from because that's not listed in the `newfiles` vector. It's also of a file type that seems unlikely to work with `read.table`.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick - I'll try that. The error message just changed and took out "_DataSummary.zip" - I am unclear on that part as well.

Comment: `full.names=TRUE` seems to work! Thank you @MrFlick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
newfiles <- dir("~/Desktop/_preFiles_byGrid", full.names=TRUE)
```

Then you can just do

```
n <- read.table(newfile, sep=",", as.is=TRUE, header=FALSE)
```

in your loop without having to worry about rebuilding the path with `file.path()` and you are much less likely to get missing file errors this way.